# ETABS OAPI setmodifier method does not work using c#

Tags: c#, api

I'm working on ETABS 2015 OAPI. The setmodifier() method for frame objects does not work. There are three function below of FrameObj class:

```
                double[] Value = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
                ret = SapModel.FrameObj.GetModifiers("1", ref Value01);
                MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString());
                ret = SapModel.FrameObj.DeleteModifiers("1");
                MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString());
                ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetModifiers("1", ref Value);
                MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString());
```

"ret" is the return value equal to zero when function work properly. The first and the second one work, but the third does not work anyway.
Somebody help me?
:)

Comment: So what is the value of ret on the SetModifiers method?

Comment: ret is 1 for setmodifiers

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that will be fixed in ETABS 2016. If you contact CSI Tech Support you may be able to get a beta build with the fix if you're enrolled maintenance, if not ETABS 2016 should come out around the end of the month.

-CSI Tech Support Engineer